# How to apply animation on image?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, animation, core-animation, uitouch

Hi I am developing a application in which where I touch on screen an image is shown at that point I am doing this in this way.

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *move = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint MovePoint = [move locationInView:self.view];
    appDelegate.FinalMovePoint=MovePoint;   

    timer =[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(Remaing) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    [self showImageWithText:@"LongBlue" atPoint:appDelegate.FinalMovePoint];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1];
    imageView.alpha = 1.0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

In this my image is shown but when the  `NSTimer` is called image get blink or get hide I need the image until the touch the `-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` method called.
Please suggest me how can I do this work.

Comment: It's a complete mystery what your code does or is supposed to do, because you didn't include the Remaing and showImageWithText methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *move = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint MovePoint = [move locationInView:self.view];
    appDelegate.FinalMovePoint=MovePoint;   

    timer =[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(Remaing) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1];
    imageView.alpha = 1.0;
    [self showImageWithText:@"LongBlue" atPoint:appDelegate.FinalMovePoint];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this also.But its didn't work. I am performing lots of comparison in the nstimer